# tomcat webapp context alias

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

I want to make a webapp running in a tomcat available under multiple contexts.

```
http://localhost:8080/foo
```

should also be available under

```
http://localhost:8080/bar
```

but I do not want to have a second web application (e.g. by duplicating the war file or symlinking)

Is there a way to create such an alias inside tomcat or do I have to use mod_rewrite in apache2? (I already use mod_jk)

Answer (score 0):

I never get such constructions working with links or duplicate the context configuration in tomcat. It produces internal errors in the webapp.

But you can use a ajp proxy in apache http configuration. This can provide the original context unter a new entry.

```
ProxyPass /original/ ajp://localhost:8010/original/
ProxyPass /test/ ajp://localhost:8010/original/
```

In my case unfortunately the webapps create links to the original context. So after some clicks the user step back to the original context again.

Comment: This solution would go around my mod_jk configuration and talk to the ajp port directly, am I right? In this case this is not suitable for me because I want to control which tomcat instance is used via the configuration of mod_jk load balancing in my workers.properties